# How can I specify number of elements in type hint sequence?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-3.5, type-hinting

I have a function that expects a two element sequence of integers. I am able to create a type hint for a tuple by doing `typing.Tuple[int, int]` and Pycharm warns me when I'm trying to pass less or more values. However, it doesn't work for `typing.Sequence`.

How can I create a type-hint for all two element sequences?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`typing.Sequence[int, int]` is an error; you're probably dealing with an outdated version of `typing` if instantiating it is a success for you.

In the latest branch of `CPython`:

```
>>> typing.Sequence[int, int]
```

results in:

```
TypeError: Too many parameters for typing.Sequence; actual 2, expected 1
```

similarly for `List[int, int]`. `List` and `Sequence` take a type for the type they hold, two types there don't make sense.

I'm guessing you should be using:

```
Sequence[Tuple[int, int]]
```

if my understanding of what you're up to is correct.